# How do I format an encrypted Integral Secure Key?

Tags: usb, disk-utility, partition, encryption, filesystem

I just bought an [Integral Secure Key from the Apple store](http://store.apple.com/ie-business/search?find=integral%20secure%20key) but am fed up with having to use its own software just to transfer files to it as it does not appear as a normal USB drive in Finder.

How can I re-format the drive so as to remove the encryption and just have a normal USB drive? Is it as simple as using disk utility?

Also how could I in the future use the encryption facilities again? Is it enough just to keep the software which is provided on the USB key?

Answer (score 1):

i have the same Integral Secure Key and i can transfer all data without any kind of encryption and store it; for all more private data i use the encryption function. so there is no need to re-format the usb to store data 'more easily"